# Upload File, file path null, VueJs / Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I try to create a simple file upload with Vuejs and Laravel. But my 'file' variable it seems to be null on post.

```
<b-form-group label-for="file">
    <b-form-file
        v-model="file"
        id="file"
        :state="Boolean(file)">
        </b-form-file>
</b-form-group>

data() {
    return {
        file: null,
    },
}
```

**and a method for post . (that works for the rest of the form)**

```
addContract(newContract) {
    post("/contracts/" + `${this.customer_id}`, newContract)
        .then((response) => {
            //
        }
        .catch(error){
            //
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
//code
    $fileName = time(). '.' .$request->$file->getClientOriginalExtention();
    $request->file->move(public_path('upload'), $fileName);
    dd($fileName);  
//code
```

**UPDATE**
I set the axios header, but now I got error 422, when it was application I didn't but it still didn't work.

```
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 }
```

Comment: Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form?

Comment: No, I have to add this?

Comment: Yes you will have to add it, otherwise you won't be able to send files with the post request. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/9193055)

Comment: I added to the from tag, also I tried like in this example. still, I got null value.

Comment: I don't know what your `post()` method does but you probably have to set the `multipart/form-data` as the header in your `post()` method.

Comment: Ok, now I have, 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' , but the data for file are still null, if I console log before post, file has value. I try to dd from controller method but it didn't get there.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the file to upload via native browser submit, you must provide a `name` for the file input (along with adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the enclosing `<form>` element).

```html
<b-form-file
  v-model="file"
  id="file"
  name="file"
  :state="Boolean(file)">
</b-form-file>
```

This is the same requirement for any form `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` control.

Comment: Same output. before put request in console log I got "file: ..." , but in the request "file: {}", and with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' , I got 422, for validation, but with application  pass validation(that is correct, for the rest of the input.)